# Can I Announce BGP By Myself?

Tags: bgp

I have /24 IP block purchased from APNIC. My ISP is not announcing my ASN. But, they gave me a static public IP that has all ports open. So can I announce my ASN using the live static IP that I have?

Comment: "_you're right I'm using a residential connection._" Unfortunately, questions about home/residential networks are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su]. You need a business network and contract with another company (ISPs are companies, too) in order to create a BGP connection and have them announce your network to their other neighbor ASes. BGP connections are taken seriously as they can damage the public Internet, and a residential connection will not be taken seriously. ISPs have no obligation to advertise prefixes that are not their own.

Answer (score 6):

BGP is a routing protocol, which means it exchanges routing information with other routers.  There has to be another router to exchange information with, and that would be a router at your ISP.

In other words, you need to "peer" (establish a BGP connection) with your ISP.  You can announce your IP block to your ISP, who will in turn announce it to the rest of the Internet.  They will probably charge you for this too.

Your ISP can give you all the details you need.

Comment: Our ISP is refusing for the announcement / peering hence I am looking if I could announce it at my end and create peer with router other than my ISP. Is this possible?
They have provided us a static IP with all ports open

Comment: Essentially, No.  If they won't peer with you, you need a different ISP,

Comment: @MohitPrajapati Possibly over some tunnel, I guess. But really, you ought to connect to an ISP that does provide IP transit or whatever services you need.

Comment: Probablly because he isn't paying them enough. Most ISPs won't do BGP for "broadband" customers.

Comment: I'd say @PeterGreen is correct. Majority of ISPs differentiate "IP Transit" and just raw Broadband Internet at different price points given the overhead of being the Transit ASN.

Comment: @PeterGreen you're right I'm using a residential connection. But the issue is my ISP is not offering any business plan. But they offered me static public IP by taking some extra charges. So I thought if I can do something using that public IP then that will be a better option for me. Because my ISP is not understanding what I need. Maybe they have some lower technical knowledge regarding the BGP announcement or it can be anything else.

By the way, thank all of you for your instructions.